# Catch invalid request & return error with feathers-sequelize

Tags: feathersjs, feathers-sequelize

I am new to feathers and am building an API, generated with feathers-cli. If the client performs an invalid GET request:

eg. `http://localhost:3030/stations/?asdfasdf`

it returns a 500 error:

`ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'stations.asdfasdf' in 'where clause'`

I'd rather not report an error like that back to the client and would instead like to return a '400 Bad Request' instead. I've tried setting up an after hook using `hook.error` but this doesn't catch the sequelize error.

How can I catch the error and return a safer, more generic message to the client?

Comment: The answer I gave should provide a generic way to deal with errors but can you also create an issue in https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-sequelize/issues/new since I think it might be something worth changing in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`error` hooks are a separate new hook type. With the 1.x feathers-cli change your [services index file](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-chat/blob/ae5f6d13bfa0daec5ba2c2104ebd807d0f99ab7f/src/services/message/index.js#L30-L34) from something like

```
// Set up our before hooks
messageService.before(hooks.before);

// Set up our after hooks
messageService.after(hooks.after);
```

To

```
// Set up hooks
messageService.hooks(hooks);
```

Then in the `hooks/index.js` [file](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-chat/blob/ae5f6d13bfa0daec5ba2c2104ebd807d0f99ab7f/src/services/message/hooks/index.js) add

```
exports.error = {
  all: [],
  find: [],
  get: [],
  create: [],
  update: [],
  patch: [],
  remove: []
};
```

You can now use it to create error hooks. For your case like this:

const errors = require('feathers-errors');

```
exports.error = {
  all: [
    function(hook) {
      if(is(hook.error, 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR')) { // Somehow check the Sequelize error type
        hook.error = new errors.BadRequest('Invalid query field');
      }
    }
  ],
  find: [],
  get: [],
  create: [],
  update: [],
  patch: [],
  remove: []
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise that error hooks were implemented in the current version. For reference, I'm using the following to grab the error code: `hook.error.original.code, 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR'`